# Find index of minimum value in a vector using R

Tags: r

Here is the example in Python which allows us to apply a function to a vector and then get the index of  minimum values of function

```
import numpy as np 
x =  np.array([ 0.0011125,  0.0135775,  0.0475375,  0.0399875,  0.0021075,
       0.3492275,  0.0065675,  0.0593175,  0.0017225,  0.0007025])
x.argmin()
# 9
```

What's the R way of doing that

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possible approach:

```
a <- c(1,0,2,3)
which(a == min(a)) # 2
```

or another:

```
which.min(a) # 2
```